is it right way to generate agora rtm token in python flask?
`# Generate agora rtm-token
I am implementing a one-to-one chat feature in my Flutter
application using Agora's RTM (Real-Time Messaging) service. I
have a Python Flask API that generates Agora RTM tokens for
users to authenticate and communicate securely. Below is the
code snippet from my Flask API for generating the Agora RTM
token:
# Generate agora rtm-token
@chat_bp.post('/agora-rtm-token')
@jwt_required()
def agora_rtm_token():
    try:
        identity = get_jwt_identity()
        user_id = int(split_token(identity))

        if not user_id:
            return jsonify({'error': not_login_error}), 400

        app_id = os.environ['AGORA_APP_ID']
        app_certificate = os.environ['AGORA_APP_CERTIFICATE']

        account = str(user_id)
        role = 1
        expiration_time_in_seconds = 360000

        tm = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=10)
        is_expire = round(tm.timestamp())
        privilege_expired_ts = is_expire


        rtm_token = RtmTokenBuilder.buildToken(app_id,app_certificate,account,role,privilege_expired_ts)

        response_data = {
            'result': {
                'rtm_token': rtm_token
             }
        }
        return jsonify(response_data), 200

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': f"{e}"})

Is this the correct way to generate an Agora RTM token? Any
improvements or suggestions are welcome.       `

